# How to skip association callback in destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

In my project, discount has and belongs to many businesses. I have an association callback rule that a discount can't remove its last businss (to maintain that there is always a businss for each discount):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses,
  before_remove: :check_count,

def check_count
  raise 'Cannot remove latest business!' if businesses.count == 1
end
```

However I realized that I won't be able to remove discounts. Since when I do `discount.destroy`, I think it will try to remove businesses, and in term will raise the error.

So is there a way around this, like some kind of `:except` as in controllers?

Comment: Check here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Comment: Link in the above comment is not working hence adding this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can call `discount.delete` which will skip the callbacks.

Comment: I still wanted to maintain integrity. I guess my callback rule was not designed properly.